# Load RGB channel to selection - Photoshop Scripting

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

So I'm new to Photoshop Scripting, but have a solid grasp of JS.

I'm trying to make a selection based on the 'RGB' channel, but my code is erroring, saying "No such element". How can I load the RGB channel in the same way as the individual Red, Green, or Blue channels? If I replace RGB with Red, everything works perfectly.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var currentLayer = doc.activeLayer;
var channelRef = doc.channels.getByName("RGB");
doc.selection.load(channelRef, SelectionType.REPLACE);
```

To clarify, I want the same functionality as clicking the 'Channel to Selection' icon in the channels panel with all channels selected.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out the answer - record the action and copy the script it outputs. Helpful for anyone else needing to do this.

```
function selectRGBChannel() {
    var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc3343 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref101 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idfsel = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
        ref101.putProperty( idChnl, idfsel );
    desc3343.putReference( idnull, ref101 );
    var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
        var ref102 = new ActionReference();
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idChnl = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
        var idRGB = charIDToTypeID( "RGB " );
        ref102.putEnumerated( idChnl, idChnl, idRGB );
    desc3343.putReference( idT, ref102 );
executeAction( idsetd, desc3343, DialogModes.NO );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no RGB channel, by definition. You probably want an array of the three color channels:

```
var channelRef = [doc.channels.getByName('Red'),doc.channels.getByName('Green'),doc.channels.getByName('Blue')];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware there is no RGB channel, but trying to copy functionality from inside the PS UI. I worked out the answer - grab the script from the logs and wrap a function name around them.